# Change the Month Number to Month name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem in java Script .

I have a `data` object that holds an array with 12 elements.

Along with that array I have 2 other objects: The first object is the month number, the second object is the month value.

How can I convert the month number into the corresponding month name?

Here is my code:

```
    data.addColumn('number', 'MonthValue');
            data.addColumn('number', 'CountValue');
            var months = [  'فروردین',  'اردیبهشت',  'خرداد',  'تیر',  'مرداد',  'شهریور',  'مهر',  'ابان',  'اذر',  'دی',  'بهمن',  'اسفند' ];
            chartsdata[1].MonthValue.toString = 'فروزدین';
            for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {

                    data.addRow([chartsdata[i].MonthValue, chartsdata[i].CountValue]);

            }
```

where `chartdata[i].MonthValue` is my month number 
and 
`months` holds the month names.

Finally I want put it into a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
months[chartsdata[i].MonthValue - 1]
```

?

(I am assuming that your MonthValue numbers are between 1 and 12; remove the `- 1` if they are from 0 to 11.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var months = [  'فروردین',  'اردیبهشت',  'خرداد',  'تیر',  'مرداد',  'شهریور',  'مهر',  'ابان',  'اذر',  'دی',  'بهمن',  'اسفند' ]

var monthNumber = 3 // Whichever month you want (counting up from 0).

console.log(months[monthNumber]) // The name for that number
```

Does that answer your question? Sorry if I've misunderstood!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want but this `months[chartsdata[i].MonthValue]` will give you month name based on value.

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand your question but i think this code will help you

```
var months = { 1 : "JAN", 2 : "FEB", 3 : "MAR", 4 : "APR", 5 : "MAY", 6 : "JUNE", 7 : "JULY", 8 : "AUG", 9 : "SEP", 10 : "OCT", 11 : "NOV", 12 : "DEC"};
    alert(months[12]);
```